# Support Object.assign in karma/protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor, angular2-cli

I have installed the latest angular-cli and the application works in a browser however when I run `ng e2e` the protractor test fails with:

```
[21:25:53] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[21:25:53] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:25:56] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ? Unable to compile TypeScript
src\app\user\user.ts (9,12): Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. (2339)
```

I take it this means I need a polyfill for `Object.assign()` however I haven't found any straightforward method that works. I've tried simply telling `tsconfig.json` to target es5 but that didn't seem to polyfill `assign`. I've also tried using babel-polyfill but I couldn't follow the setup process so I'm not sure I did it correctly. I'd prefer a "lightweight" solution anyway.

I'm looking for something that is compatible with the environment created by `angular-cli` version 2.3.1 (Node 6.9.4)

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention the issue is in the TestBed feature which I assume runs components in `node` rather than the browser. The code that fails specifically is:

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  providers: [AuthService]
});
```

I was able to fix the error by hacking my assign call as `(<any>Object).assign( this, values )`. This wasn't needed to run the same code in the browser or even the e2e tests without `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`. I really don't understand TestBed but I'm using it because it seems to be the way to to components inside e2e-spec files.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: No, this does mean that you need to configure TS properly. What did make you think that you need to polyfill it? You will have hard time finding Chrome version that doesn't support `assign`.

Comment: @Aravid: The code is `Object.assign()`. The issue is that protractor doesn't seem to natively support it. If there is any useful code I could post I would.

Comment: @estus: Chrome supports it just fine. The issue seems to be the protractor testBed can't run it (it can't compile code that includes Object.assign()).

Comment: Protractor itself doesn't support anything. It uses a browser to run code. If you have problems with protractor, please, post the error that you have.

Comment: @estus: I don't think that is true for the TestBed module. I think it instantiates objects outside the browser (I assume that's why it's compiling typescript).

Comment: Again, there's no error that indicates that assign should be polyfilled. All that was posted is TS error. If you're concerned with Node, it surely supports assign. Having core-js for polyfills is always preferable in A2 app, but it is not a primary problem here.